# Java Замена фрагмента строки(!) в файле

Tags: java, файлы

Есть некий файл, в котором каждая строка вида
*login/password/type/int*

Мне нужно поменять переменную `int` не добавляя новую строку, нужно только его заменить. Деление строки использую `split("/")`;

Я нашёл ответ, но там менялись все фрагменты в файле, а не построчно.

Comment: Используйте StringTokenizer, String s1 = st.nextToken() где nextToken() ваш разделитель "/", Ну и собственно считывание построчно делайте с помощью LineNumberReader

Comment: @GenCloud А как заменить то в файле строку?

Comment: new StringTokenizer("/"); Выборка элементов по символу "/" в строке. Считываете данные, к примеру, грузите их в объект класса Params, и функцией replace(value_to_replace, new_value) меняете параметры

Comment: @GenCloud То, как в строке все поменять это понятно. Мне надо чтобы эта строка которую я токенайзером прочпокал запихнулась в файл вместо начальной строки

Comment: Ну тк в чем проблема собственно не понимаю, выгружаем из памяти, создаем новый файл, и записываем в него новые данные -> try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("./somefile.txt", false)) { .... writer.write(yourString}; writer.append('\n'); ....  writer.flush(); }

Comment: @GenCloud Проблема в том что у меня там не одна строка, а небольшая база данных.

Comment: сори но facepalm -> я ведь написал, грузим в коллекцию, меняем значения на какие хочеться, выгружаем из коллекции посредством list.stream.forEach(string -> ..., и пишем эту реализацию в врайтер

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону RandomAccessFile.
вот как пример http://devcolibri.com/2989

Answer (score 0):

- [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) по вашему символу (`/`)
- [`LineNumberReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)'ом грузим весь массив строк в [`List<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- меняем содержимое коллекции уже на ваши хотелки
- выгружаем из коллекции данные `list.stream.forEach(string -> ...`
- записываем в файл [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)'ом.

Comment: Можно скинуть пример в коде, я просто новичок во всяких потоках